# Using the camera modes in Rocket League

Tags: rocket-league

In Rocket League, you can keep the camera facing forward or locked onto the ball.  Usually I go the entire match using the camera that locks onto the ball.  This gets a little disorienting when the ball goes high and your car scrolls out of view.  When should I be using each of the two camera modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's completely up to you. I used to like the fixed camera back in SARPBC but since I've gotten used to the ball cam in Rocket League, I prefer that one much more any time I'm trying to track the ball.

It's a lot easier if you can get used to one camera mode, but if you really want to switch off, use the fixed camera when you want to know where **you** are and the ball cam when you want to know where the **ball** is.